# Accumulate objects of the same class within a class member function

Tags: c++

I've the following class. When I calculate the _avg_lifespan by Method 1 (commented) it compiles, however it doesn't compile with Method 2 using std:accumulate. Why?

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Raven{
    public:
        Raven()
        {
            _lifespan = rand() % 15;
        }
        int sum_life(int sum, Raven *rhs)
        {       
            return sum + rhs->get_lifespan();   
        }
        void set_avg_lifespan(vector<Raven*> flock)
        {
            //Method 1 works :-)
            /*
            int sum = 0;
            vector<Raven*>::iterator it = flock.begin(); 
            while( it < flock.end() )
            {   
                sum += (*it++)->get_lifespan();
                cout << sum << endl;
            }
            _avg_lifespan = (float)sum/flock.size();
            */
            //Method 2 does not work :-(    
            _avg_lifespan = (float)std::accumulate(flock.begin(), flock.end(),0,sum_life)/flock.size();
        }
        int get_lifespan( ) { return _lifespan; }
        float get_avg_lifespan( ) { return _avg_lifespan; }
    private:
        int _lifespan;      
        float _avg_lifespan;
};
```

The error is:

```
argument of type ‘int (Raven::)(int, Raven*)’ does not 
match ‘int (Raven::*)(int, Raven*)’
```

Comment: sum_life is a member function, and as such is looking for a member argument (this is bad). Make sum_life static.

Comment: A better way to do this would be to use boost::make_transform_iterator() to automatically access the get_lifespan() method every time you read from the iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that Raven::sum_life is a member function.
Thankfully, you can use [std::bind](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/) and pass "this" as the first argument.
Your code would look like:

```
auto f = std::bind(&Raven::sum_life, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
_avg_lifespan = (float)std::accumulate(flock.begin(), flock.end(),0,f)/flock.size();
```